# "Every-day" in Past Tense

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Can the adverb "every day" be used in Simple Past Tense? I've seen plenty of online journalists writing articles by putting "every day" in the Simple Past Tense's sentence.

So.....Is this correct? 
If yes, then how should we construct a Past Tense sentence with the adverb "every day" in it? (Give plenty of examples, please)

Thanks a lot
David

Comment: Do you have some reason for thinking that this is not grammatical? _I saw them every day._ seems completely unexceptionable to me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems perfectly correct to me. It refers to a habit in the past and it might be used in sentences like "When I was a kid I went skating every day". Another way to refer to a habit in the past is the use of the modal verb WOULD as in "When I was a kid I'd (would) go skating every day".

Comment: 'every day' may refer to a habit but it does not specifically refer to the past.

Comment: I agree, but my answer referred to the specific question above.

Comment: Ah, okay. It was the ambiguity that confuzzled me. You said, "It seems perfectly correct to me.  It refers to a habit in the past... "  but you didn't unambiguously tie down what 'it' refers to. I obviously picked the wrong 'it'.

Answer (score 1):

**every day** can be used in any tense. You asked for examples:

In Summer, I go swimming every day. [simple present]

When the holidays arrive, I shall go swimming every day. [future]

When I stayed with my friends by the coast, I went swimming every day. [simple past]

I have been swimming every day this week in order to improve my fitness. [present perfect]

I thought I had been swimming every day but I hadn't -- I blame the drugs. [past perfect]

By next Thursday evening I will have been swimming every day for a whole year. [future perfect]

I would have gone swimming every day, but for my broken wrist. [past conditional perfect (or something)]

To go swimming every day is my goal for 2016. [infinitive]

Answer (score 0):

I am curious what your line of thought is, that drove you to this question.

The specific phrase "every day" simply means "each day", or "daily". I can't think of a way that the tense of the sentence might change how this is expressed.